# Java GC log file handle leaked to child processes

Tags: java

We use JVM options `-verbose:gc` and `-Xloggc:<path>` to log garbage collection events to a file. As expected, the Java process holds a lock to the GC log file.

Where it gets weird is when we spawn a child process, the child process also holds a lock to the GC log file. This is an issue because when our main Java process exits, we can't delete the GC log file until the child process also exits.

This is surprising because Java is supposed to use flag `FD_CLOEXEC` when opening files to avoid leaking file handles to child processes. Why is it different for the GC log file? Any workarounds other than disabling GC logging?

The code below shows a simple Java applications that opens a file and launches a sub-process that just hangs for 3 minutes before exiting. When GC logging is enabled, **the child process** holds a lock on the GC log file (unexpected), but not the regular file `my-file.log` (expected).

```
// VM options:
// -verbose:gc -Xloggc:C:/test/log/gc.log

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    // Open a file for writing
    new FileOutputStream("C:\\test\\log\\my-file.log");

    // Start sub-process, but don't wait for it to exit
    List<String> command = Arrays.asList("C:\\test\\log\\wait_test.bat", "180");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process childProcess = pb.start();

    // Wait 30 seconds
    Thread.sleep(30 * 1000L);

    // Exit without killing process or closing file
    System.out.println("Exiting with process running: " + childProcess.isAlive());
}
```

The contents of `wait_test.bat` is as follows:

```
@echo off
REM %1 Time to wait in seconds
ping -n %1 localhost >nul
```

This was tested under Windows 7 using Java version 1.8.0_101.

**Update**: Reported bug to Oracle as [JDK-8176717](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8176717).